# Flask Error when refreshing page ('NoneType')

Tags: python, mysql, flask

Dear Python community,

I have encountered a problem that I can't get solved. I recently moved to a macOS Sierra Version 10.12.6.

All I am doing is connectedly to a MariaDB Mysql database. When staring the program the initial connection and response works and hence all the output is there, however when I refresh the page I get a "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable". If I restart the program in the terminal it will work again - until I refresh....

Here the code:

```
from dbhelper2 import DBHelper


app = Flask(__name__)
DB = DBHelper()

@app.route('/trtdtable')
def trtdtable():
    try:
        tabledata = DB.table_inputs()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        tabledata = None
    return render_template("trtdtable.html", tabledata=tabledata)
```

second part (the DB helper)

```
import pymysql

# Connect to the database
connection =  pymysql.connect(host='localhost',user='root',password='',db='test',cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

class DBHelper:

    def table_inputs(self):
        try:
            query = "SELECT PersonID, LastName, FirstName, Address, City FROM persons";
            with connection.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor) as cursor:
                cursor.execute(query)
            return cursor.fetchall()
        finally:
            connection.close()
```

and the HTML (in "trtdtable.html"):

```
<table id="customers">
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>Last Name Name</th>
              <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Address</th>
              <th>City</th>
            </tr>

           {% for row in tabledata %}
           <tr>
             <td>{{ row['PersonID'] }}</td>
             <td>{{ row['LastName'] }}</td>
             <td>{{ row['FirstName'] }}</td>
             <td>{{ row['Address'] }}</td>
             <td>{{ row['City'] }}</td>
           </tr>
           {% endfor %}

   </table>
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're closing the connection after the query. Don't do that.

Also, never ever catch and swallow all exceptions. If you didn't have that blank `except`, Flask would have told you what the error was.

Comment: It appears that he isn't simply swallowing the exceptions but is trying to return them. I think that have 'print(e)' instead of 'return(e)' is the issue with the statement.

Comment: Thank you guys for your quick replies. I tried both suggestions, but could not fix the bug. For me the strange thing is that the code works when I start the .py file from the terminal and navigate to the page .../trtdtable for the first time. Only when refreshing or re navigating the route for a second time does the error occur. So one would think that there is a difference between the first use and all subsequent uses of the route; which has never happened to me before..... thank you

Comment: try:
        tabledata = DB.table_inputs()
    except Exception as e:
        return(e)
        tabledata = None

Comment: But that isn't anything at all to do with what I said. The problem is that you're calling `connection.close` after doing the query, so when you come to refresh the page it tries to use a closed connection. Stop doing that. *And*, stop catching all exceptions; it's not whether you print them or return them, it's that you're catching them at all. Don't do that either.

Comment: Daniel you are right! I do not understand why this solved the issue (and probably I did not do it in the best possible way, but if I replace the "connection.close()" statement with "connection.cursor" it solved the issue! if there is a better way I would of course appreciate your comment since on my "Windows" computer the code worked. thank you